# Missing "Command Bar" in "Windows Explorer" of "Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard"

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-server-2012-r2, toolbar

I cannot find the *Command Bar* (with *Organize*, *Properties*, *System Properties*, etc.) in *Windows Explorer* of *Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard*. The image shows an example of the *Command Bar* as it is visible on another computer with *Windows 10*. I cannot reactivate it with `View` > `Options` > `Restore Defaults` for all options. How can I make the *Command Bar* visible in *Windows Explorer* of *Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard*?

[image]

Comment: The ribbon in Windows Server 2012 R2 only has File, Computer and View. Which Command Bar are you looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server 2012 R2 is based on the Windows 8.1 interface, so don't compare it with Windows 10.

However, all operating systems mentioned above **never had** the command bar – all of them use the "Ribbon" interface. The last OS which had the command bar in Explorer was Windows 7 (and Windows Server 2008).

Your Windows 10 computer had the command bar installed through a third-party addon, most likely the one called "OldNewExplorer".

Answer (score 1):

I do not see an actual "Organize" button or icon, but System Properties are certainly there.  Click on the Computer tab and much of what we use is right there.

[image]